# Two questions on Elias Stein paper (1976)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

I am working on some results related with a paper of Elias Stein (on the almost every where convergence of wavelet summation methods), and I have the following questions:

1. The maximal function operator of $f$ in the Elias Stein paper (1976) is bounded on $L^p({\mathbb R}^ n)$, whenever $p > n/(n - 1)$, and
   $n \ge 3$. Does it stay bounded when we define the maximal function on the new space $L^2(S^2)$?

and

2. How can I define the maximal function operator when the function is in $L^2(S^2)$?

Comment: Could you refer to the original Stein paper?

Comment: I think the OP is referring to one of my first papers, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1420506 , though I don't know why it would be relevant to spherical averaging.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're asking if Stein's result extends to $R^2$ for $p>2$. This was proved in

*J. Bourgain*, MR 874045 [**Averages in the plane over convex curves and maximal operators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02792533), *J. Analyse Math.* **47** (1986), 69--85.

See

*W. Schlag*, MR 1388870 [**A generalization of Bourgain’s circular maximal theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-97-00217-8), *J. Amer. Math. Soc.* **10** (1997), no. 1, 103--122.

for a discussion and more precise results.

**Edit:** Following Terry's comment/interpretation, it may be that the OP is asking about the operator that maps functions on the sphere $S^2$ to the sphere by taking the maximal average of circles on the sphere centered at a given point.

This should be be bounded for $p>2$. Heuristically one would like to stereographically project the problem from (a cap on) $S^2$ back to $R^2$ and then apply Bourgain's theorem. The complication is that while a stereographic projection takes circles to circles, it will not preserve the property of a circle being centered at a given point. However the family of circles centered at a given point under the preimage of the stereographic projection should satisfy Sogge's cinematic curvature condition, and thus the result should follow from C.D.Sogge, [Propagation of singularities and maximal functions in the plane](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01245080), Invent. Math. 104 (1991), 349-376.

Comment: It may be that the OP is interested in "variable coefficient" versions of these theorems suitable for curved manifolds such as $S^2$.  In this case one can look at Chapter XI.3 of Stein's "Harmonic analysis", which basically shows that the results of Stein extend to variable coefficient settings so long as a "rotational curvature" condition is satisfied.  In 2D one needs a "cinematic curvature" condition; see Chapter XI.4.D of Stein.

Comment: @TerryTao (and/or Mark Lewko): do you have a good idea which paper(s) the OP is referring to (in the versions of the question before the edit by Leitão)? I suppose an answer to that would also answer the question of whom he is addressing.